# Debian 12 freezes and crashes after installation

Tags: crash, debian, freeze, reboot

**After installing Debian 12, my laptop (Victus 16) with an AMD Ryzen 5 5600H CPU, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU, and 16GB RAM freezes and reboots within about 3 seconds of login.** This happens whether I use the common ISO file or the edu ISO file. My bit depth is x64.

Comment: How can we help? In any case this is a site for programming questions, so your question is off-topic. In any case. Try not to use any NVIDIA binary drivers (it takes time for them to build, and quality is not great in any case [it is not a market their care]

Answer (score 0):

After using nomodeset for troubleshooting, add `nouveau.modeset=0` to grub to solve the problem.